# when i create table with data from api the rows are duplicated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import './user.css'

const User = ({ id, email, name, onDelete }) => {

    const handleDelete = () => {
        onDelete(id);
    }

    return (
        <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>edit</th>
                    <th>delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{name}</td>
                    <td>{email}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button>edit</button>
                        <button onClick={handleDelete}>delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    )
}

export default User
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new table for every user. That's why your headers are duplicated. You only need a new row for every user instead of an entire table for each user.

I'd separate the UserTable and the UserRow.

```
// UserTable.jsx
import React from 'react'
import './user.css'
import './UserRow'

const UserTable = ({ users, onDelete }) => {

  return (
    <table className='table'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>edit</th>
          <th>delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        {users.map(user => {
          <UserRow key={user.id} userId={user.id} userName={user.name} email {user.email} onDelete={onDelete} />onDelete={onDelete} />
        })
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

export default UserTable
```

```
// UserRow.jsx
import React from 'react'
import './user.css'

const UserRow = ({ userId, email, userName, onDelete }) => {

  const handleDelete = () => {
    onDelete(userId);
  }

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{userName}</td>
      <td>{email}</td>
      <td>
        <button>edit</button>
        <button onClick={handleDelete}>delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
}

export default UserRow
```